# append 3rd `<td>` value in highchart's tool tip

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

The snippet below displays tooltip like `Colin Cockram : 601118.076`  with the currency symbol. 
How can i append my 3rd `<td>` values in this tooltip ?

Need tooltip like `Colin Cockram : 601118.076 - Survey : 891`.

How can i achieve this ?

```js
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            data: {
                table: 'datatable'
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Survey Reports Chart'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            yAxis: {
                allowDecimals: true,
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Amount'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: \u00a3'+Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.y, 2);
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {column: {colorByPoint: true}},
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
        });
    });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<table id="datatable" style="display:none;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th> Test </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Gavin Leney</td>
            <td>13592.400</td>
            <td>39</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Colin Cockram</td>
            <td>601118.076</td>
            <td>891</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alan Alker</td>
            <td>152274.000</td>
            <td>235</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better way to do this by making your data source as json objects rather than dataTable

Get your data to the chart using **series**

> series: [{
>                         data: [{
>                            name: 'Gavin Leney',
>                            y: 13592.400,
>                            z: '39'
>                        },{
>                        name: 'Colin Cockram',
>                        y: 601118.076,
>                        z: '891'
>                    },{
>                        name: 'Alan Alker',
>                        y: 152274.000,
>                        z: '235'
>                        }]
>                    }],

and then you can get rid of your **data**

> data: {
>                   table: 'datatable'
>               }, //This is no longer needed as you are feeding data with **series**. Also, now you can get rid of your entire html for data table.

See the working code below: [NOTE: I have not added all the data in series.]

```js
    $(function () {
            $('#container').highcharts({
                
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Survey Reports Chart'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: ''
                },
                yAxis: {
                    allowDecimals: true,
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Amount'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: \u00a3'+Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.y, 2) +' - <b>Survey</b>: '+ this.point.z;
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                      data: [{
                         name: 'Gavin Leney',
                         y: 13592.400,
                         z: '39'
                     },{
                     name: 'Colin Cockram',
                     y: 601118.076,
                     z: '891'
                 },{
                     name: 'Alan Alker',
                     y: 152274.000,
                     z: '235'
                     }]
                 }],
                plotOptions: {column: {colorByPoint: true}},
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
            });
        });
```

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Buddy but i am redering  my table dynamically,. its not static. else i could do it easily .

Comment: I am guessing you  are creating the datatable in loop dynamically (from the database). If that is the case, get your data from database and convert it into json object. Then you can use this json object to feed entries to both dataTable and highchart.

Answer (score -1):

My solution is quite hacky jQuery wise. It's not done via the recommended highcharts way but I don't have that much time on hand to read through their documentations.

This piece of code searches for the TD with the text of the current point in the chart and then hops over two spots to get the number in the 3rd td element. The text is then included in the tooltip formatter

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        data: {
            table: 'datatable'
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Survey Reports Chart'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: true,
            min: 0,
            title: {
            text: 'Amount'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: \u00a3'+Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.y, 2) + ', Survey: '+ $('td:contains("'+ this.point.name +'")').next().next().text();
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {column: {colorByPoint: true}},
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: In this case if you have the same name in other <td> the information displayed is going to be wrong.

Comment: @JorgeMejia Indeed it is. Hence why I said it's kind of a hack and not a proper way to fill the chart. I have no prior experience with highcharts or how to set it up so I was not aware that you can generate it way more easily by passing variables to it. Aside from that on the x-axis I don't know if the OP will have duplicate names, if not then this is a possible way of appending text to the tooltips. Don't quite get why you would downvote my answer. The question was how to append text to the 3rd td element and I gave an example. Just because you don't like the answer doesn't mean it's wrong.